# Why is compiler using non specialized template?

Tags: c++, templates

I was implementing a function to sort different containers containting different types.
I have created template as such:

```
template<typename Container>
void mySort(Container& container)
```

And it works for all the purposes I need it to, however for an argument being char[][] I want to change the implementation, so I declared template specialization as such:

```
template <>
void mySort<char**>(char**& container)
```

But my program is still using the generic implementation. What is causing this behaviour, have I made mistakes in declaring the specialization?

Comment: Plz, show the container you used

Comment: @KonradP The type char ( * )[N] to which a two-dimensional array is implicitly converted and the type char ** are two different types.

Comment: We can't take it on faith that the argument you're providing is, in fact, `char**`. *Show the code*. A proper [mcve] will belay all the banter and drive *exactly* to your problem. It is highly likely you template specialization doesn't match what you think it does, but that is guesswork and soothsaying. *Show the code*.

Answer (score 1):

For the `char[][]` version, you could provide

```
template <int N, int M>
void mySort (char (&container) [N][M]); // version 1
```

and the correct function-template will be instantiated, and called.

Given the other function-template

```
template<typename Container>
void mySort(Container& container) // version 2
```

you can use them like this

```
std::string s;
mySort(s); // calls version 1
char c[10][10] ;
mySort(c); // calls version 2
```

Note that there is no specialization going on here. These are separate function-templates entirely.